# sap.m.table pagination issue

Tags: sapui5

table defined as follows

```
    <Table id="idSC_HdrList" mode="MultiSelect" editable="false" 
                             growing="true" growingThreshold="10"
```

A search function populates the table from an Odata call, the first result works fine.
[image]

However when I click on the More button, the number of records correctly show 20 rows ( 10 + 10 ), but the more button overall count has jumped from 39 to 49.

[image]

This continues on each subsequence more button

[image]

Anyone come across this before and why this is happening? I have set the binding to one way on the odata model (not sure if it has anything to do with it, but it was mentioned in the growing property)

Comment: I don't have any code for this, the following properties growing="true" growingThreshold="10" on the table i believed should take care of this functionality? It kinda does, but each time i click on the more button, it automatically adds the previous displayed records to the end of the table.

Comment: Would help to see the backend configuration

Comment: Apologies, what do you mean by backend configuration? I'm not lazy loading, the initial 39 records are returned by the oData read, i just can't understand how the table row count grows every time i hit the more buton. The extra rows added are the same rows that are already displayed.

Comment: Provide your Component.js for example. How have you "attached" your OData service? It seems like you've done something wrong. Either your OData service or your attachment to it seem to have some misunderstandings

Comment: And maybe you should give us your search function too so we can help

Answer (score 0):

OK, thanks for the comments on this question, when I was copying out the code to give more details for the Odata service in Component.js, I noticed I had disabled the setCountSupported on the service.

Once I commented this out and re-tested, the pagination function works correctly now.

```
//oModel.setCountSupported(false);
```